# Regex for selecting beween (' and '

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, regex-negation

I tried looking for an answer, but no answer suited my needs...

This is my code:

```
<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', 1);"></button><p>6 Bacon</p></div>

<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', 1);"></button><p>3 Paprika</p></div>

<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', 1);"></button><p>1 Sliced Meat</p></div>
```

I would like to capture the words between 
`svg onclick="addIngredient('` And the `'`

after the word. So I for example would like to retrieve the word `Bacon`, `Paprika` or `Sliced Meat`

I tried doing this, but it just didn't work..

```
var stringy = '<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', 1);"></button><p>6 Bacon</p></div>

<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', 1);"></button><p>3 Paprika</p></div>

<div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', -1);"><path></path></svg>
<button onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', 1);"></button><p>1 Sliced Meat</p></div>';

var result = stringy.match("svg onclick="addIngredient(([^}]*)')");
console.log(result);
```

How can I do it right?

Comment: Using jsdom to extract the onclick attribute first. (or the following paragraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression. It uses `.*?` to match the least character possible until it comes to the next `'`

```
<svg.+?onclick="addIngredient\('(.*?)'
```

Here is a running example. You need to use the `.exec()` function to only get the `$1` group of every occurence.

```js
var stringy = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML; // read the HTML instead of hard-coding it here as a string
var regex = /<svg.+?onclick="addIngredient\('(.*?)'/g;
var match = regex.exec(stringy);

while(match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(stringy);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', -1);"><path></path></svg>
    <button onclick="addIngredient('Bacon', 1);"></button><p>6 Bacon</p></div>

    <div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', -1);"><path></path></svg>
    <button onclick="addIngredient('Paprika', 1);"></button><p>3 Paprika</p></div>

    <div><svg onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', -1);"><path></path></svg>
    <button onclick="addIngredient('Sliced Meat', 1);"></button><p>1 Sliced Meat</p></div>
</div>
```

---

Just for improving your regex skills an explanation of your mistakes:

```
var regex = "svg onclick="addIngredient(([^}]*)')";
                         ^             ^   ^ ^  ^
```

1. You need to escape the `"` with a `\` because your whole regex expression is surrounded with " (JavaScript strings)
2. You need to escape the `(` with a slash, because a bracket is the beginning of a regular expression group.
3. Why are you looking for a set without a `}` in it? You can just look for any character (`.`).
4. If you are using the `*` without an `?`, it will be greedy and only stop at the last occurence in your document. Usually, you want the selector not to be greedy.
5. The last bracket is again a special character, which needs escaping. You don't necessary need this bracket, because it would obviously already be enough to stop at the `'`.

Comment: You are great! Thank you so much! Looking for this for almost a week and you solved it in no-time! Also thank you so much for the explanation, as it helps a lot!!